# Как сделать на CSS неполную обводку круга?

Tags: css

Как на CSS сделать неполную обводку круга?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: да, это возможно.

Comment: А как это сделать-то?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29649643/how-to-create-a-circular-countdown-timer-using-html-css-or-javascript

Comment: Там SVG. На CSS этого сделать нельзя?

Comment: вот тут есть ответ с примером:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13059190/html5-css3-circle-with-partial-border

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вот так будет универсальнее - можно длину обводки настраивать по желанию:

```css
.pie {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: .5em;
  width: 8em;
  height: 8em;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.pie:after {
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: block;
  content: "";
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
    left: .5em;
  top: .5em;
  height: 7em;
  width: 7em;
}



.p1 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(-30deg, #ddd 50%, transparent 50%),
                    linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, steelblue 50%);
}

.p2 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, steelblue 50%);
}

.p3 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(150deg, transparent 50%, steelblue 50%),
                    linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, steelblue 50%);
}

.p4 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(270deg, transparent 50%, steelblue 50%),
                    linear-gradient(180deg, #ddd 50%, steelblue 50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="pie p1"></div>
<div class="pie p2"></div>
<div class="pie p3"></div>
<div class="pie p4"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот так ?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}
div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 10px solid red;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 300px;
  margin: 20px auto;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: А дальше с помощью CSS можно развернуть круг как вам нужно

Comment: @Abmin не обязательно , можно любую часть квадрата убрать или как вы сказали повернуть

Comment: так же можно с помощью `:before` и `:after` зарисовать рамку

Comment: и так тоже, ваша правда

Answer (score -1):

Возможно вы имеете ввиду вот так:

```css
.not-full-circle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 5px solid rgb(101, 152, 218);
  border-right-color: transparent;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  margin: .5em;
}

.not-full-circle::before {
  content: attr(data-number);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  color: rgb(51, 102, 168);
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', Arial;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: 100;
}
```

```html
<div class="not-full-circle" data-number="7"></div>
<div class="not-full-circle" data-number="78"></div>
<div class="not-full-circle" data-number="260"></div>
```

---

Или может вот так:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.progress-circle {
  --color: rgb(101, 152, 218);
  --color-2: rgb(240, 240, 240);
  --circle-size: 100px;
  --border-width: 10px;

  width: var(--circle-size);
  height: var(--circle-size);
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: .5em;
  background-image: conic-gradient(var(--color) var(--progress), var(--color-2) 0);
  position: relative;
}

.progress-circle::before {
  --inner-circle-size: calc(var(--circle-size) - var(--border-width));
  --inner-circle-gap: calc(var(--border-width) / 2);

  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: var(--inner-circle-size);
  height: var(--inner-circle-size);
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  left: var(--inner-circle-gap);
  top: var(--inner-circle-gap);
}
```

```html
<div class="progress-circle" style="--progress: 25%;"></div>

<div class="progress-circle" style="
--progress: 50%;
--color: red;
--border-width: 15px;
"></div>

<div class="progress-circle" style="
--progress: 75%;
--color: rgb(76, 240, 52);
--color-2: rgb(175, 33, 255);
--circle-size: 150px;
"></div>

<div class="progress-circle" style="
--progress: 42%;
--color: green;
--color-2: red;
--circle-size: 150px;
--border-width: 15px;
"></div>
```

#### Использование

Всё *очень* просто, вот пошаговая инструкция:

1. Создаёте `<div>`, чтобы получилось вот так: `<div></div>`
2. Выдаёте ему класс `progress-circle`, чтобы получилось вот так: `<div class="progress-circle"></div>`
3. Выдаёте ему атрибут `style`, с таким значением: `--progress: ПРОЦЕНТ_ЗАПОЛНЕНОСТИ%;`, чтобы получилось вот так: `<div class="progress-circle" style="--progress: 42%;"></div>`

Вы также можете выдавать доп. параметры для прогресса, по типу:

- `--border-width` - ширина самой границы (прогресса)
- `--color` - цвет, которым закрашивается текущий прогресс
- `--color-2` - цвет, которым закрашивается оставшаяся часть не заполненного прогресса
- `--circle-size` - размер круга.

Всё максимально удобно и легко настраивается, требуются лишь навыки HTML, как работает RGB / HEX / HSL и немного познания в величинах в CSS'e.

#### Внимание товарищи!

Убедитесь что у вас установлена минимальная необходимая версия браузера для работы моего решения. (Всё потому что я использую `conic-gradient`)

| Браузер | Версия |
| --- | --- |
| Firefox | 83 |
| Chrome | 69 |
| Opera | 56 |
| Edge | 79 |
| Safari | 12.1 |